# Predicting using gp.predict for input vector of more than one dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I want to fit and predict using Gaussian Process Regression in my data set which has input vector of 3 dimension and 1D output. Is there a way to predict using gp.predict using scikit learn? But its showing the error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Code:

```
import xlrd
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import (RBF, Matern, RationalQuadratic)
from sklearn.metrics.classification import accuracy_score, log_loss

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn; seaborn.set()  # plot formatting    

loc = ("C:/Users/yash.bagla/Documents/ML Project/Data/Data_LowGain_Reg_63C.xlsx") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

X_d = []
Y = []  
# For row 0 and column 0 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

for i in range(sheet.nrows - 1):
    X_d.append((sheet.cell_value(i+1, 0), sheet.cell_value(i+1, 1), sheet.cell_value(i+1, 2)))
    Y.append(sheet.cell_value(i+1, 4))

X_l = np.reshape(X_d, (-1, 3))

nsamples, nx = X_l.shape
X = X_l.reshape((nsamples,nx))

X1 = np.linspace(0, 0, 3)[:, None]
X2 = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)[:, None]

X1_test, X2_test = np.meshgrid(X1, X2)
X_1 = np.reshape(X2_test, (-1, 3))
nsamples, nx = X_1.shape
X_ = X_1.reshape((nsamples,nx))

kernels = [1.0 * RBF(length_scale=3.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0)),
           1.0 * RationalQuadratic(length_scale=3.0, alpha=0.1),
           1.0 * Matern(length_scale=3.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0),
                        nu=1.5)]

for fig_index, kernel in enumerate(kernels):

    # Specify Gaussian Process
    gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)

    y_mean, y_std = gp.predict(X_[:, np.newaxis], return_std=True)

    y_samples = gp.sample_y(X_[:, np.newaxis], 10)

    # Generate data and fit GP

    gp.fit(X, Y)

    # Plot posterior
    y_mean, y_std = gp.predict(X_[:, np.newaxis], return_std=True)

    y_samples = gp.sample_y(X_[:, np.newaxis], 10)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\yash.bagla\Documents\ML Project\Code\Edit5_GPR_1.py in <module>()
     55     plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
     56     #X_ = np.linspace(0, 25, 1000)
---> 57     y_mean, y_std = gp.predict(X_[:, np.newaxis], return_std=True)
     58     plt.plot(X_, y_mean, 'k', lw=3, zorder=9)
     59     plt.fill_between(X_, y_mean - y_std, y_mean + y_std,
C:\Users\yash.bagla\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\gpr.py in predict(self, X, return_std, return_cov)
    312                 "returning full covariance.")
    313 
--> 314         X = check_array(X)
    315 
    316         if not hasattr(self, "X_train_"):  # Unfitted;predict based on GP prior
C:\Users\yash.bagla\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    568         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    569             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 570                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    571         if force_all_finite:
    572             _assert_all_finite(array,
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Please let me know how to tackle input vectors with more than 2 dimensions.
Thanks.

Comment: Please see [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); getting rid of the unnecessary plot commands (which are irrelevant to your issue, and just create clutter), you see that you are calling `predict` before `fit`, which may or may be not relevant to the issue but it is certainly wrong...

Comment: thanks. I'm calling predict before fit to plot prior and calling it again to plot posterior.